# How to surrender to God alone?

Tags: vishnu, belief, krishna, practice

I have gone several posts here, Lord Krishna says if you want to stay out of this all materialistic life surrender to me alone. But all these social culture forces us to get trapped again to this what our ancestors did. Seems like an never ending process to me.

If someone gets married and after some years he leaves everything and surrenders to god, is it a right thing? Will not be a sin that he left his family (wife) alone to struggle?

Mythologically, is it really mandatory for someone to get married? If yes then 
What is the right way to surrender to God?

Comment: renunciation is internal and not external. External renunciation (taking sanyaas) is of no use at all by itself. The important thing is to take up internal sanyaas. Your mind should have no control over you. You should be the Master of your senses. One should not leave one's family unless it is decreed by the Guru (or by God) isn't it. In fact being with family and performing all family responsibilities, without being attached to their outcomes while remembering God who resides in your heart is the greatest of all Yogas.

Comment: Agreed @Sai your statement is quite practical to current life style we all have right now and can be done. But i was little eager to know about how to make a deep connection with lord Krishna and surrender .. But gradually i feel somehow getting trapped (PS:- getting  married soon :-/ ) into all these social,emotional attachments with family and friends which we hardly can leave. So what i am concluded from this discussion is that do ur job, take care of ur belongings and give as much time you can to Lord Krishna. thanks!

Comment: Yes it is not a trap at all. World is like a Gym sir. Gym is filled with equipment such as weights, running, etc. The one who goes to gym has to undergo the heavy training. Then only he can build muscle and lose fat. Similarly the world is like Gym. It is filled with responsibilities. The one who has come to this world has to undergo these, so that One can lose the Ego. The sanyaasi's are of highest cadre. They did not renounce for running away from responsibility. They are the Gym trainers. They are the guides for all humanity. Thus no need to renounce for sake of getting trapped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scriptures say that if you are going to live in the world then you should marry. If you do not want to marry, take up sannyas, surrender to God. Krishna says in the Gita (XVIII. 66.)

> "Abandon all dharmas and come to Me alone for shelter. I will deliver you from all sins; do not grieve."

Sankaracharya says that one should take to sannyas when one has the longing to do so, one should not wait. Ramakrishna Paramahamsa gives the following example: A man was told by his wife that he should become a better man by following the example of his neighbor who was renouncing things slowly, bit by bit. The man turned to his wife and said 'I will show you real renunciation' and threw down his towel and walked away never to return.

If you are already married, then to take to sannyas and leaving your wife may be a great sin. One must make sure that one is running towards God and not simply running away from his worldly responsibilities. The wife should be provided for. In such a case it is best to have a Guru and to take the Guru's advice. Every case in such an instance is different.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if nothing is a compulsion. All is a matter of situation. Suppose you are a kind of a person who is so mentally engaged in thought of Lord that you do fulfill the basic requirements of family by going for job earning money for them but as soon as you leave your office your mind and heart will crave to drown themselves in the eternal pleasure of thoughts of Any form of supreme god. Just like a lover loves to sit isolated thinking about his beloved, don't bothering about what is happening around him. Your spouse will not entertain such behavior. As according to her it us she or he who deserve to stay in your thoughts and heart and not the invisible or myth Lord Krishna. So it would always be better to get separate. Because separation exists where thought and desire don't match. Lord is not an option rather he is the only solution. If family doesn't accept your way of life it's not your problem...God doesn't deserve to be left for the sake of pleasure of family who can't cope with you. Specially when they demand something from you which you have already lost to your Lord your special wala love.

Secondly to achieve a heigher aim you have to sacrifice smaller aim only if they are coming in way of your progress. If you have been promoted you have to leave your previous job profile and dedicate it to someone else so that you can fulfill the requirements of your current bigger role. If our freedom fighters would have thought like why to sacrifice my life for others sake?...who will support my family after vi will die..or even my family can get into a trouble by doing so... then we would not have attained independence. Attaining the eternity it the supreme goal of being born in a human body. If your family support you in attaining your beloved goal then it's good , but if they put obstruction and hindrance they you must move on and they have to learn moving on. Many DID the same in past.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange! You should cite some sources.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to remember we have come alone and going alone and we have to think just like valmiki that no one is going to share our bad deeds even if it committed for the good of the near and dear. Always keep your mind fixed in the services of god (here service to humanity is service to god). Therefore have compassion towards all living beings and do whatever possible and needful to the needy even if that living being is not known to us previously or in any way related to us unless through a chance contact or getting know of their situation through distant news media. Where ever it is at least pray for their well being and also tried to find out someone to help even if you are not able to directly help them.